# Container declaration with template

Tags: c++, containers

What do these two statements literally mean? Are they simply two initializations or something else?

```
template <class T, size_t N> class array;
template <class T, class Alloc = allocator<T>> class deque;
```

Comment: Please specifically clarify each word if can. Thank you!!!

Comment: Not sure if such question will be well received here, friend. You may want to rephrase your issue?

Comment: Ok, somebody did that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have given two known classes ie `array` & `deque` so one can tell you in detail about the meaning of those syntax. It's because we know how they are implemented.

First case: The statement tells that the programmer needs two inputs to create an object of `array` type. For ex :-

```
array<int, 5> a;   // creates an array of 5(ie N) integers(ie T)
```

We can comment on this thing because we know what `array` is. Similarly for `deque` we can have :-

```
deque<int, SomeAllocator> d;     // creates a deque container of integers(ie T) having a custom allocator named SomeAllocator (which must be an allocator of integers)
```

As you are a newbie so it would be better if you just assume `allocator` as another class that will `allocate` space, `create` objects, `destroy` objects & finally `deallocate` the space.

Once again we can comment on the above because we know what `deque` is. However if you write something like :-

```
template <class T, size_t N> class A;
template <class T, class Alloc = allocator<T>> class D;
```

Then you code would simply mean two declarations where `A` takes 2 parameters in the `<> parenthesis`: one data type (means any type like `int`, `double`, or `some class`, etc) & one `size_t` type & `D` also takes 2 parameters: one data type (again any type) & an `allocator` of that data type.

Answer (score 1):

They declare (but not define) two templates for classes.  In the first case the template arguments are an arbitrary type (presumably the type of the element of the array), and a number (presumably the number of elements of the array).  In the second case the template arguments are both types, but the second type has a default (which depends on the first type).

Comment: Thank you! Although I can't fully understand your explanation. It's really hard for a newbie to understand all the terms since it usually leads to a situation that I have to go link by link in order to understand all the things...

Comment: Yes.  Your problem is that StackOverflow is not a tutorial site.  Find a good tutorial book (and I think you need dead trees, rather than a website), and work through it.  I don't know what a good book is these days - I learnt from "The C++ Programming Language", but that's only good for learning C++90 if you are an experienced C programmer.  C++11 /14 is a significantly different (better) language, so you need a more modern book.